# How Connect a separate (JS component Bootstrap 5) in NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-5

I have Bootstrap5 installed, I only want to include a few components from Bootstrap5 sources, how do I do that?

**package.json**

```json
{
    "name": "Blog",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nuxt",
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "start": "nuxt start",
        "generate": "nuxt generate"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@nuxtjs/svg": "^0.3.0",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "core-js": "^3.19.3",
        "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
        "webpack": "^4.46.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "pug": "^3.0.2",
        "pug-plain-loader": "^1.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.47.0",
        "sass-loader": "^10.2.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you saw that kind of functionality somewhere in the documentation? It needs to be supported, not all CSS frameworks allow this (a few that my knowledge actually).

Comment: Yes, I saw it, and I used it on my projects

Comment: Where and how did you achieved that?

Comment: Bootstrap 4
import Tooltip from "~/node_modules/bootstrap/src/js/tooltip"

This is work on Webpack! but i wanth Use Nuxt and Bootstrap 5